# Advanced numpy indexing

Tags: python, numpy

Here is what I want to do with numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random((10,321,321))
y = np.random.rand((10,21,321,321))
z = np.random.randint(0,21,size=(10,321,321))

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(321):
        for k in range(321):
            if x[i][j][k] <= 0.5:
               for l in range(21):
                   if l == z[i][j][k]:
                       y[i][l][j][k] = 1
                   else:
                       y[i][l][j][k] = 0
```

What would be the better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use `np.identity` to create a complete set of one-hot vectors and select the appropriate ones using advanced indexing:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random((10,321,321))
y = np.random.rand(10,21,321,321)
z = np.random.randint(0,21,size=(10,321,321))

yc = y.copy()
yct= yc.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)
yct[x <= 0.5] = np.identity(21, dtype=yc.dtype)[z[x <= 0.5]]

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(321):
        for k in range(321):
            if x[i][j][k] <= 0.5:
               for l in range(21):
                   if l == z[i][j][k]:
                       y[i][l][j][k] = 1
                   else:
                       y[i][l][j][k] = 0       

print(np.all(yc == y))
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility:

```
tmp_y = np.zeros_like(y)

for l in range(21):
    tmp_y[:, l, :, :] = (z == l).astype(dtype=np.int32)

y = np.where(x <= 0.5, tmp_y, y)
```